# how to make ScrollView scroll under the real RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

The under code is an `XML` layout I am trying to make the `Scrollview` to Scroll under the `RelativeLayout` of the image and the image layout still in its position but all Layout scroll how can I solve the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:theme="@style/no_title"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/real"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
        >
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/person_ic" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_info"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/USerNameLayout"  
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc">
                    <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/NameStudentRe"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="#ffff"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:hint="   Name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:text=" Sukaina Ahmed Al-Mutawakel"
                    android:textColor="#cccccc"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works. The textview scroll under the layout of the image and the layout doens't move.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/test_stackoverflow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

</RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/test_stackoverflow">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I solved by change the android:layout_height="200dp" for the scrollview @ImNeos